# LaTeX cannot find a lot of packages!

Tags: fonts, errors

When I try to compile a file, it gives errors and the output is only math accents. Plain text is not displayed.

Here is the log file:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1200

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1200

! I can't find file `ecrm1200'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecrm1200.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1200' failed to make ecrm1200.tfm.

kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1728

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1728

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1728

! I can't find file `ecrm1728'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1728 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1728 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecrm1728.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1728' failed to make ecrm1728.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecbx1728

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1728

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecbx1728

! I can't find file `ecbx1728'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1728 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1728 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecbx1728.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1728' failed to make ecbx1728.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm0900

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0900

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm0900

! I can't find file `ecrm0900'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0900 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0900 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecrm0900.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0900' failed to make ecrm0900.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecbx0900

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0900

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecbx0900

! I can't find file `ecbx0900'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0900 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0900 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecbx0900.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0900' failed to make ecbx0900.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecti0900

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti0900

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecti0900

! I can't find file `ecti0900'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti0900 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti0900 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecti0900.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti0900' failed to make ecti0900.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm0800

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0800

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm0800

! I can't find file `ecrm0800'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0800 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0800 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecrm0800.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0800' failed to make ecrm0800.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm0600

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0600

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm0600

! I can't find file `ecrm0600'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0600 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0600 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecrm0600.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm0600' failed to make ecrm0600.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecbx1200

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1200

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecbx1200

! I can't find file `ecbx1200'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1200 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1200 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecbx1200.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1200' failed to make ecbx1200.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecti1200

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti1200

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecti1200

! I can't find file `ecti1200'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti1200 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti1200 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecti1200.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecti1200' failed to make ecti1200.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm eccc1200

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input eccc1200

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf eccc1200

! I can't find file `eccc1200'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input eccc1200 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input eccc1200 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: eccc1200.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input eccc1200' failed to make eccc1200.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecbx0800

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0800

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecbx0800

! I can't find file `ecbx0800'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0800 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0800 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecbx0800.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx0800' failed to make ecbx0800.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1440

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1440

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1440

! I can't find file `ecrm1440'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1440 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1440 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecrm1440.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1440' failed to make ecrm1440.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecbx1440

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1440

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecbx1440

! I can't find file `ecbx1440'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1440 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1440 Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: ecbx1440.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecbx1440' failed to make ecbx1440.tfm.

Process exited with error(s)
```

The files start with `ec` and have various latter letters such as `ecrm` `ecbx` etc. What would be the problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit operating system on VM Workstation.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
  }

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Math
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[noline, noend, ruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{bl}{rgb}{0.0,0.2,0.6} 
\definecolor{dark-red}{rgb}{0.4,0.15,0.15}
\definecolor{dark-blue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.4}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, linkcolor={dark-red},
    citecolor={dark-blue}, urlcolor={medium-blue}
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec} 
\newtheorem{observation}{\textsc{Observation}}
%%% Start of the document
\begin{document}
This is a test document with $n$ number of lines. $\dfrac{4}{5}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a small MWE?

Comment: This looks like an incomplete installation; can you try doing `apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`?

Comment: @egreg YES! That's the solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should install all packages in the `texlive` family that bear the name `recommended`; in general I recommend a full install, so these problems are solved at the beginning. However, the package that contains the source for the European Modern fonts are installed by

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

This should get you in synch. However, this installs only the bitmapped version and you need also

```
sudo apt-get install cm-super
```

for the Type1 version, or the result won't be very good.

In any case, the `texlive-fonts-recommended` package contains the Latin Modern fonts also in Type1 version, so you can simply add

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your file and you will have no reason to worry.

Comment: This solved my Asian fonts issue (error I was getting: `! I can't find file tcss1000.`).

Answer (score 3):

use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
...
```

Comment: now, only ecrm1200 is missing. What is the reason this order fixes the compilation?

Comment: Instead of `\usepackage{lmodern}` try `\usepackage{kpfonts}`. And install the font package cmsuper. TL 2013 is an old TeX distribution.